# Translational invariance of Haar measure under tensor products

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, tensor-products, random-matrices, haar-measure

Consider a $4 \times 4$ Haar-random unitary $U$. By the right translational invariance of the Haar measure, for any $4 \times 4$ unitary $A$, $U A$ is still a Haar-random unitary.

Now, consider two $4 \times 4$ Haar-random unitaries, $U$ and $V$, and consider the following $16 \times 16$ matrix $Q$:

\begin{equation}
Q = (U \otimes V) ~(I_{2 \times 2} \otimes A \otimes I_{2 \times 2}),
\end{equation}

where $A$ is a $4 \times 4$ unitary and $I_{2 \times 2}$ is the $2 \times 2$ identity matrix.

Can it be written as a tensor product of two $4 \times 4$ Haar random unitaries? If not, is $Q$ a $16 \times 16$ Haar random unitary?

Note that since we cannot directly multiply $A$ with either $U$ or $V$, the translational invariance of the Haar measure cannot be directly used.

Comment: Note that as $U(4)$ has dimension $4^2$, and $U(16)$ has dimension $16^2$, its impossible for $Q$ to be Harr-distributed as the distribution of $Q$ must be supported on a $2*4^2$ dimensional subspace.

Comment: I did not get the comment. Doesn't $Q$ also have dimension $16^{2}$?

Comment: Does your comment imply $Q$ can neither be a $16 \times 16$ Haar random unitary nor be written as a tensor product of two $4 \times 4$ Haar random unitary? If so, might you elaborate it into an answer instead of a comment?

Comment: Their both $16$-by-$16$ matrices, but the distribution of $Q$ is defined by a smooth function on $U(4)\times U(4)$, which is 32-dimensional. On the other hand $U(16)$ has dimension 256, so the map cannot possible induce the Harr measure on $U(16)$, so $Q$ is not Harr distributed. This aurgument says nothing about wheather its is still a tensor product of Harr random matrices, as this is true for example if $A$ is composed on block 2-by-2 matrices.

Comment: What if A cannot be decomposed into a tensor product of 2x2 matrices? 

Can we then say that Q is not a tensor product of Haar random matrices?

Comment: For generic $A$, it is not even true that $Q$ is generically a Kronecker product. I don't know a proof, but you can check this numerically.